# Error when using Canvas to preview SwiftUI view

Tags: xcode, swiftui

When I try to preview my SwiftUI view in the Canvas window in Xcode, my project builds successfully but I get the following error in the Canvas window:

> UVIntegration.DTXMessageError.messageRepliedWithError("Connecting to
>   launched interactive agent 6310", Optional(Error
>   Domain=com.apple.dt.ultraviolet.service Code=17 "connectToPreviewHost:
>   Failed to connect to 6310: Error Domain=RemoteBundleLoaderError
>   Code=17 "Failed to load library
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XCPreviewKit.framework/Versions/Current/XCPreviewKit
>   due to missing bootstrapping symbols"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to load library
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XCPreviewKit.framework/Versions/Current/XCPreviewKit
>   due to missing bootstrapping symbols}"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=connectToPreviewHost: Failed to
>   connect to 6310: Error Domain=RemoteBundleLoaderError Code=17 "Failed
>   to load library
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XCPreviewKit.framework/Versions/Current/XCPreviewKit
>   due to missing bootstrapping symbols"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to load library
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XCPreviewKit.framework/Versions/Current/XCPreviewKit
>   due to missing bootstrapping symbols}})))
>
> ---
>
> GenericHumanReadableError: unexpected error occurred
>   messageRepliedWithError("Connecting to launched interactive agent
>   6310", Optional(Error Domain=com.apple.dt.xcodepreviews.service
>   Code=17 "connectToPreviewHost: Failed to connect to 6310: Error
>   Domain=RemoteBundleLoaderError Code=17 "Failed to load library
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XCPreviewKit.framework/Versions/Current/XCPreviewKit
>   due to missing bootstrapping symbols"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to load library
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XCPreviewKit.framework/Versions/Current/XCPreviewKit
>   due to missing bootstrapping symbols}"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=connectToPreviewHost: Failed to
>   connect to 6310: Error Domain=RemoteBundleLoaderError Code=17 "Failed
>   to load library
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XCPreviewKit.framework/Versions/Current/XCPreviewKit
>   due to missing bootstrapping symbols"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to load library
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XCPreviewKit.framework/Versions/Current/XCPreviewKit
>   due to missing bootstrapping symbols}}))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clean Build Folder, then kill Xcode, start Xcode, do a full Build may (sometimes) fix the problems. Then the whole circus starst again.
I think it is a bit of a shame on Apple. Most frustrating of all (for me at least) is that documentation is virtually non existing. It is all trial and error. Mostly error.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue twice now. I haven't got an easy solution, but it happened only when there was a software update for macOS Catalina available. For example, right now, I'm on 10.15.5, but there is a update for 10.15.6, and I'm having this issue.

Hope that helps, and it is really annoying the error doesn't just say "Update your macOS" or something.